# How To Export/Import WordPress (MySQL) Database Properly Via Command-Line?

Tags: database, mysql, import, export, command-line

Normally, a MySQL database can be exported and imported using these simple SSH commands:

**Export:**

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME > filename.sql
```

**Import:**

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME < filename.sql
```

But it's not that simple when it comes to WordPress. From what I see, additional parameters need to mentioned, such as `--add-drop-table` for instance.

The WordPress Codex does [provide some info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database#Using_Straight_MySQL_Commands), but it looks cluttered and not clear enough.

It would be great if someone who uses command-line can share the proper commands to export and import a WordPress database, with some explanation (of any new parameters used).

Also, are there any reasons why it wouldn't be advisable to use command-line when dealing with database, and instead go with a GUI like phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is that simple for Wordpress too. I use the following to back up my WP sites:

```sh
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD --quick --extended-insert DBNAME > backup.sql
```

[The mysqldump document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) gives the details on all the parameters.

`--extended-insert` is quicker when updating a DB from a dump file and makes the dump file smaller.

`--quick` makes the creation of the dump quicker.

You don't really need to use either of those, just makes things a bit quicker and writing an insert for each row just makes me feel happier - your original dump syntax would be just fine.

Don't forget though that there is domain-specific entries in the DB so if you are using this method to backup/restore then you are fine but if you want to move from one.com to two.com then you will need to edit entries in `wp_options` after you restore your dump.

Comment: But how about `--add-drop-table` and stuff like that mentioned on the codex page? http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database#Using_Straight_MySQL_Commands - are you sure they aren't necessary?

Comment: It's not needed, with the options I use the dump files all have this before the create table and subsequent inserts:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `<wp_tablename>`;

so the tables are always dropped and then created, then data inserted into them

Comment: Concurring with Steve, your original commands of `mysqldump -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASE_NAME > filename.sql` and
`mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASE_NAME < filename.sql` 
would work just fine. The only thing to be really wary of is running string replaces in between export and import if moving between domains.

Comment: As an update regarding the options: this is from the mysqldump documentation:

Some mysqldump options are shorthand for groups of other options:

Use of --opt is the same as specifying --add-drop-table, --add-locks, --create-options, --disable-keys, --extended-insert, --lock-tables, --quick, and --set-charset. All of the options that --opt stands for also are on by default because --opt is on by default.

Comment: also useful for migration is adding `--compatible=mysql40`

Answer (score 2):

Having invested the time to learn the basics of the command line, I am using phpMyAdmin less and less now.
However, I do find it easier when I need to browse or edit an entry (such as editing the `wp_options` entries, as Steve mentions above).
I also used to go to the GUI when I wanted to exclude a particularly large table (such a plugin's logs) which didn't need backed up. But I've discovered you can just add

```
--ignore-table=my_db_name.my_table_name my_db_name
```

Answer (score 0):

For copying a site to a new location.

use --add-drop-table during export, if you're importing to an empty database. 
omit --add-drop-table during export, if you're importing to merge the database.

Remember to update wp_options after import each time, since path is different. 
Also, update the .htaccess file with new path.